# How to display YouTube suggestions as interaction options

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, distube

How could I display YouTube autofill suggestions while a user is inputting a string? I'm using DisTube and the `searchSongs` option but that only affects the result of already inputting a text. I've seen bots such as Soul Music effectively pull it off so it's clearly possible but I'm not sure how they exactly did it.

[image: interaction displaying query as YouTube search suggestions]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is achieved with the help of something called Autocomplete in `discord.js`. It's actually pretty simple to do something like this. The first step is to declare an autocomplete command. This can be done in the [`SlashCommandBuilder`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/builders/main/class/SlashCommandBuilder) by using the option [`.setAutocomplete()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/builders/main/class/SlashCommandStringOption?scrollTo=setAutocomplete). An example:

```js
const data = new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('command-name')
    .setDescription('command-description')
    .addStringOption(option => {
        option
            .setName('option-name')
            .setDescription('option-description')
            .setAutocomplete(true)
    })
```

Then, you just have to create an event listener for the [`interactionCreate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Client?scrollTo=e-interactionCreate) event, and then when it fires, check if the interaction was an Autocomplete request and respond with a value. An example:

```js
client.on('interactionCreate', (interaction) => {
    if (!interaction.isAutocomplete()) return
    const enteredValue = interaction.options.getFocused()
    const values = [
        {
          name: 'option-name',
          value: 'option-value',
        }
    ]
    interaction.respond(values)
})
```

If you want to learn more about the Autocomplete feature, I'd suggest you go here => [Autocomplete | discord.js](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/autocomplete.html#autocomplete)